# DataTable .filter() and clearFilters() hides messages p:messages and p:growl

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2.2

My issue when I use:

```
<p:growl id="growl" autoUpdate="true" />
```

or

```
<p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" />
```

When I have error message, and once I use clear filters or re filter for primefaces datatable like :

```
<p:commandButton value="do somthing and re-filter" oncomplete="PF('testTable').filter()"/>

<p:commandButton value="do somthing and clear filter" oncomplete="PF('testTable').clearFilters()"/>

<p:dataTable id="table" widgetVar="testTable" value="#{myMB.data}">
</p:dataTable>
```

The messages got hidden, that because the autoUpdate is true, so ajax call for filter fired and return with no messages so this call clear messages, will be a solution if I make `autoUpdate="false"` but I needed it so I don't want to set it to false.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solution is to add ajax filter event to the `p:datatable`:

```
<p:dataTable id="table" widgetVar="testTable" value="#{myMB.data}">
    <p:ajax event="filter" ignoreAutoUpdate="true" />
    {...}
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I spent a week looking for the solution to this problem

Comment: This still isn't working for me. The growl is rendering and immediately vanishing still. My growl component has globalOnly = true - I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: @GreenieMeanie If it's only global and its showing then it not make difference, but try remove it, but anyway, there might be another "event" call the ajax, maybe not filter, or maybe you have misspelling? It MUST work, make sure that growl is outside your container that you updating if you do, ex: if you update="@form" then make sure that growl is outside the h:form, because updating the growl will re-render it, or just remove the update in ajax tag, no need for it at all in this case.

Comment: For me worked using <p:ajax event="filter" global="false" />