# Primefaces datatable clearFilters() breaks RequestContext update()

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am working on a project using JSF2.2 and Primefaces 6.1

We encountered numerous problems with Primefaces datatable filters. Most of them has been somehow corrected by browsing the internet for answers, but for this last one I'm finally asking for your help.

Here's the **context**:

We have a page representing a model entity details page, let's call it Person.
This entity can have links to several other model entities of another type, let's say Organization.

So in the detail page of a Person I have a datatable presenting all its linked Organizations, with pagination and filtering features enabled...

Here's modified but representative code for the xhtml page:

```
<h:form id="personForm">
  <!-- Irrelevant Person attributes panel -->
  <p:panel />
  <!-- Organization links datatable panel -->
  <p:panel toggleable="true" collapsed="true">
    <p:datatable id="organizationsTable" var="organizationDto" value="#{personView.organizationDtos}" widgetVar="organizationsTableWidget" paginator="true" rows="10" first="personView.first" paginatorTemplate="Whatever...">
    <!-- Table content -->
    </p:datatable>
  </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Now for the content of the table, the first column is actually a button to delete the row, and in the header of the column a '+' to add an Organization to the list:

```
<p:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <p:column>
      <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-plus" action="#{personView.chooseOrganization()}" immediate="true" update="searchDialog" oncomplete="PF('organizationsTableWidget').paginator.setPage("PF('organizationsTableWidget').paginator.cfg.pageCount - 1);">
      </p:commandButton>
    </p:column>
  </f:facet>

  <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-close" action="#{personView.removeOrganization"} >
  </p:commandButton> 
</p:column>
```

Other columns are simple attributes of the Organization entity, with a filter in the header as such:

```
<p:column headerText="Organization ID" filterBy="#{organizationDto.id}" filterMatchMode="contains">
   <h:outputText value="#{organizationDto.id}" />
</p:column>
```

Now, clicking the '+' button open a search dialog permitting the user to search and select an Organization to add to the datatable of Person:

```
private void onOrganizationChosen(OrganizationDto organizationDto) {
organizationsDto.add(organizationDto);        
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("personForm:organizationsTable");
}
```

Finally, the page contains a Save button which persists the modifications, reload the Person entity, and clear the filters of the datatable.

```
<p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{personView.save()}" update="personForm" oncomplete="PF('organizationsTableWidget').clearFilters()" 
</p:commandButton>
```

Now **the problem**:
Before any save action has been triggered (therefore clearFilters() method has not been called), adding an Organization successfully updates the datatable (the new Organization is immediately visible in the page.
But if the user performs a Save action (triggering the clearFilters() method) , any added Organization afterwards is not displayed in the table (the update is not done) BUT the entity is actually in the model: if the user change the filters in the datatable or re-save (or if I call clearFilters() on the table from Firebug console), the new Organization appears...

I checked the AJAX response, and in the not working case, the response contains an unmodified version of the datatable.

I could probably provide more details but since this post is already long and I'm not sure what is and what is not relevant, feel free to ask for additional informations.

Thanks for all the help you can give.

**EDIT**: I found a workaround

I noticed that the AJAX request issued by clearFilters() method set the parameter personForm%3AorganizationsTable_filtering to true, as if an actual filter was being used... And by browsing several problems encountered by other users, it seems that once filters are being used on a table, it cannot be udated by AJAX, without calling Widget filter() method on it afterwards.

Therefore I edited the method :

```
private void onOrganizationChosen(OrganizationDto organizationDto) {
  organizationsDto.add(organizationDto);     
  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("personForm:organizationsTable");
  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('organizationsTableWidget').filter()");
}
```

Update of the table is now performed when adding a new Organization, even after a clearFilters() call (through Save button).

I find this very messy, but it will do for now.
Please let me know if you have a better solution to the problem.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [mcve]. Then you automaticall y separate relevant from irrelevant parts. Lots of text that help clarify the problem to a certain extend, but to little code to try to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I'll try to reproduce a minimal version of the problem but I don't have much time right now and the real page is quite complex. In the meantime I thought maybe someone would have encountered a similar issue and coul have some idea about what is happening here. But I'll work on the example.

Comment: Good investigation. Can you please add this to the PrimeFaces issuelist in github? And maybe try 6.2-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: @Kukeltje yoo dude I see this been happening alot xD im gonna try this guy workaround on my problem, and also gonna try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541645/datatable-filter-and-clearfilters-hides-messages-pmessages-and-pgrowl, I already have a workaround but lets see if this ones works too

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast: Better to ALSO create an issue in the primefaces issuelist with an [mcve]  in the PrimeFaces format (for https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test and create it in there) Otherwise it won't get any real attention.

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast: if there is a real PF [mcve] I can see if I can track it down.

Comment: @Kukeltje I will try brother, the thing is that this bug appears sometimes other times it doesn't, in my case in some views it affects the growl or the datatables filters get screwed (won't reset) or both sometimes, or none, and I analize the differences in the views and its none, so its weird bug mate, but I will try if I get some time too, so far I understand that clearFilters() does an ajax call so it affects in that way, but its weird that sometimes calling clearFilters won't work on table, wish you could see my project like on a skype call or something like that.

Comment: @BugsForBreakfast: Don't forget, this is not your question ;-)